# read dynamic length content using msgrcv

Tags: linux, ipc, message-queue, msgrcv

I use msgrcv function  to read  message from message queue. It works fine when I read known   length data. Some cases my message length is variable. In such How can i allocate only require amount of memory and read the message from message queue without losing any data from message queue. Please give idea to overcome this issue.

Note:
In IBM message queue, when we read exceeded length data,  it fills the actual size of the message into structure which we are passing mqget function. Like this, Is there any way to do this operation in  message queue.

Answer (score 0):

From my brief reading of the [`msgrcv()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/msgrcv) man page, if your buffer size is too small and you don't specify the `MSG_NOERROR` flag, `msgrcv()` will return -1 (with errno set to `E2BIG`) and leave the message in the queue.

In this case, you could double your buffer size (up to `MSGMAX`, which is 8192 on linux by default) and try again.